# i wrote an incomplete delay time Program, i need help to continue

Tags: java, input, time, java.util.scanner, delay

```
package programmierAufgaben_Blatt2;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Aufgabe4 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
```

// Here i give which hour

```
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Geben Sie bitte die Stunde ein (00-23): ");
        int stunden = s.nextInt();
        
        if (stunden < 0 || stunden > 23) {
            System.out.println("Fehler : Geben Sie bitte eine Stunde im Bereich zwischen 00 und 23. ");
        }
        
        s.nextLine();
```

// Here i give which Minute

```
        System.out.println("Geben Sie bitte die Minuten ein (00-59): ");
        int minuten = s.nextInt();
        
        if (minuten < 0 || minuten > 59) {
            System.out.println("Fehler : Geben Sie bitte eine Minute im Bereich zwischen 00 und 59. ");
        }
        
        s.nextLine();
```

// Here i give the delay time

```
        System.out.println("Geben Sie bitte die Verspaetung in Minuten ein (00-59): ");
        int verspaetung = s.nextInt();
```

// i dont know what i should code here...

// Here is the result

```
        System.out.println("Die neue Ankunftszeit ist: "  );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your program supposed to do?

Comment: I enter a time ,for example 
what hour: 10
what minute : 30
delay time : 45
the program should print out the new time, which is : 11:15

Comment: So can you write a formula how to calculate that on a paper? What about if the new time crosses midnight? What if the delay is longer than 24 hours?

Comment: the formula is what i dont know how to write.    all what you said is right but i dont know how to continue

Comment: An hour has 60 minutes. You can convert everything to minutes, add the minutes together and then convert minutes back to hours + minutes. If you use `int` for operands, `x / y` will give you an integer divisor and `x % y` will give you the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding this code to that missing section:

```
// Calculate neue Ankunftszeit ist
int newMinutes = minuten + verspaetung;
int newHour = stunden + newMinutes / 60;
newMinutes = newMinutes % 60;
newHour = newHour % 24;
```

... and then for that last line, append the result by concataening the *newHour* and *newMinutes* components, after formatting them as 2 digit String values:

```
// Display the result
System.out.println("Die neue Ankunftszeit istz: " + 
    String.format("%02d", newHour) + ":" + String.format("%02d", newMinutes));
```